# Can I get GF4 to log to log4j?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, log4j, glassfish-4

Just to make myself clear. My application does log properly with log4j. What I would like is to also change GF java logger to log4j and remove the ugly and useless
`2013-10-22T18:52:15.199+0100|INFO:`
from my console appender.

Ideally I would like to be able to use GF4 threshold hot-change capabilities as well. I am using commons-logging in my application to log to log4j, so in theory if I can get GF to use commons-logging that would be great.

Is it possible?

Thanks